# Reset the columnWidth?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

is it possible to reset the columnWidth for the masonry layout? I'm using media queries so would like to dynamically update the width.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. See [how to do it here](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/fluid.html).